# How to take in a filename from argv and use it with ifstream / change it to txt for ofstream?

Tags: c++

I know how to iterate through the argv parameter but what I want to do is take the filepath and use that the argument in my ifstream and ensure it's the right format (.DAT), but then for my ofstream, use the exact same path but with a .txt extension instead.

Comment: so make a copy of the string and append ".txt" to the end? What trouble are you running into? Please show your code.

Comment: The arguments are full filepaths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would pass the desired "base" name as the argument. Then, when you try to open it as an `ifstream`, add the `.DAT` extension yourself and check that the file exists. If so, just append `.txt` for your ofstream and write to that file.

For instance, you would call: `myapp.exe inout`

Then, you would check for the input filename:

```
std::ifstream ifs(std::string(argv[1]) + ".dat"); // reads from inout.dat
if (ifs.fail()) ...

std::ofstream ofs(std::string(argv[1]) + ".txt"); // writes to inout.txt
if (ofs.fail()) ...
```

**EDIT:** You have added the important detail that you're dragging `.dat` files onto your executable. In that case, you'll have to remove the extension yourself. Something like this should work (but is *not* error tolerant!):

```
std::string basename = argv[1]; // take the whole path, including dat extension (DAT EXTENSION!)
basename.resize(basename.length() - 3); // remove dat extension (hah!)
std::string outname = basename + "txt"; // add the output extension
```

Note: This code is untested and is not robust in the least. It assumes every file you pass it has a three letter extension.

Comment: Right now I am just dragging the .DAT file over my executable. The resulting argv is a list of filepaths that already come with .DAT included in the path

Comment: then, remove the ".dat" from the end of the string and replace with a ".txt"

Answer (score 0):

I would lookup for the position of the last occurrence of ".DAT" in your argument with a call to rfind, then get a substring to the resulting position, to which you can append the .txt,something like that :

```
string fullPath = string(argv[1]);
size_t pos = fullPath.rfind(".DAT");
if (pos == string::npos)
{
//fail
}else{
string outfilePath = (fullPath.substr(0,pos)).append(".txt");
//write to file
}
```